# What happens to LDAP user authentication and NFS home directory shares when away from the network?

Tags: home-directory, nfs, ldap, user-data

At present I have several machines on the home network which are a mixture of static desktops and laptops. Its getting unmanageable for me and impractical for all of them to have local home directories, settings and security so I am considering using LDAP for common user management and NFS for shared home directories.

What happens when one of the laptops are out on the road? The home network is unreachable so will auth fail and fall back to local storage? Also, when the laptop returns is there a way to resync the home storage to the NFS server?

Answer (score 6):

Neither NFS nor LDAP support disconnected operation: i.e., when the
laptop cannot reach the servers, it will not be able to access any
NFS-mounted directories, nor will it be able to perform user lookups.
Basically, it will be stuck.

A couple of workarounds could be the following.

Instead of mouting home directories via NFS, you could keep local
directories an use
[unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to synchronize
them with the one on the central server.  You can run unison from
cron, guarded by a test that aborts operation if the server is
unreachable. [This post on
AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1895/how-should-i-synchronize-configurations-and-data-across-computers)
and [this other
one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69/keeping-multiple-workstations-in-sync)
provide a discussion on the topic of synchronization and some useful
suggestions.

Regarding the user authentication/authorization problem, solutions
revolve around using the `libnss-db` as a source for user
information:

- Install `libnss-db`, then configure `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to look up
  the `db` source in addition to the regular `files`:

  passwd: files db
    group: files db
    shadow: files db

  The `db` source files are located in `/var/lib/misc`
  (`/var/lib/misc/passwd.db` etc.).  You can then keep a master copy
  of these files on your central server and synchronize the clients
  with `rsync`+`cron`.  Disadvantages: there are no ready-made
  management scripts to manage the db files on the server (that I know
  of), plus you incur a synchronization delay and have to setup a way
  for `rsync` to connect to the master server.
- The  `nss-updatedb` and `libpam-ccreds` packages provide a cleaner
  way to set this up: with `nss-updatedb` you can recreate locally the 
  `passwd.db` and `group.db`, whereas the `shadow` information is
  managed by `libpam-ccreds`.  Instructions how to set these up can be
  found in the `README` files accompanying the packages.

Comment: @Jorge: thanks a lot for this suggestion! I've updated the answer text.

Answer (score 2):

#### Files

As for files, I would go for a net based sync for common files (say [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) or [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)) and then have a shared folder for bigger files (maybe Music, Photos, Video and Ubuntu ISOs). This could be an NFS mount, that when it fails doesn't matter too much, or a Samba share, or probably one of a number of other technologies.

#### LDAP

LDAP failing definitely causes trouble. All sorts of system accounts you're normally unaware of can't be translated (name <-> id number) and the system will, at best, repeatedly hang for a minute at a time while waiting for a response from the LDAP server before falling back to the local system. Or the system might just lock up and fail completely.

There are [some ways around this](https://serverfault.com/questions/55724/linux-console-is-unusable-when-ldap-server-is-down/). You can set up a local copy and sync it, in various ways - see other answers to this question and to the linked question. You can also tell LDAP to not get the system users from the LDAP directory, but from local files. On our servers we have put the following at the end of our `ldap.conf`

```
# We need to ensure that various things can work without LDAP being available
# for example: booting, ssh in as root, apache ...
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers avahi,avahi-autoipd,backup,bin,daemon,dhcp,dhcpd,games,gdm,gnats,haldaemon,hplip,irc,klog,libuuid,list,lp,mail,man,messagebus,munin,mysql,nbd,news,ntp,nut,polkituser,proxy,pulse,root,sshd,statd,sync,sys,syslog,uucp,www-data
```

You would want to make sure that all system users are in that list. Even then it's probably not enough for laptop usage.

From the [nss_ldap man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/nss_ldap.5.html)

```
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers <user1,user2,...,userN>
          This option directs the nss_ldap implementation of initgroups(3)
          to return NSS_STATUS_NOTFOUND if called with a listed  users  as
          its argument.
```

So basically LDAP pretends it doesn't know those users without even contacting the master server, so the NSS falls back on the local users and the system works fine.

One last idea is that if you're willing to spend the time learning LDAP, you could instead learn some basic [puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)) and use that to keep all your users the same across all systems - see [this puppet recipe](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/User_And_Homedir_Recipe_Patterns) for example. Puppet will allow you to do a lot of other things aswell - installing common packages, common set up of various aspects ...